# How can I prevent Pivot_Wide from adding new rows in my data?

Tags: pivot, tidyverse, case, mutate

This is a dput()sample of my data:

```r
structure(list(ID = c("101", "101", "101", "101", "101", "101", 
"101", "101", "101", "101", "101", "101", "101", "101", "101", 
"101", "101", "101", "101", "101", "101", "101", "101", "101", 
"101", "101", "101", "101", "101", "101", "101", "101", "101", 
"101", "101", "101", "101", "101", "101", "101", "101", "101", 
"101", "101", "101", "101", "101", "101", "101", "101"), IDA = c("1000", 
"1279", "1392", "534", "835", "910", "748", "589", "675", "500", 
"1243", "635", "1181", "791", "755", "1069", "640", "1229", "1856", 
"116", "767", "1126", "863", "1141", "1858", "899", "5", "225", 
"175", "1764", "1017", "497", "771", "41", "816", "1046", "439", 
"930", "1350", "641", "1057", "1021", "503", "553", "1738", "1379", 
"774", "442", "1113", "1503"), DATE = structure(c(1497315600, 
1552352400, 1552957200, 1390438800, 1439427600, 1479776400, 1455757200, 
1402534800, 1409187600, 1383008400, 1536022800, 1414630800, 1545094800, 
1551142800, 1461805200, 1483405200, 1420506000, 1534813200, 1493600400, 
1348448400, 1458176400, 1521075600, 1464656400, 1527555600, 1504573200, 
1478134800, 1278378000, 1320886800, 1309395600, 1598576400, 1500512400, 
1385600400, 1436403600, 1284426000, 1430960400, 1485824400, 1381971600, 
1477962000, 1510023600, 1420509600, 1508806800, 1499302800, 1386205200, 
1379466000, 1555290000, 1565226000, 1435798800, 1494896400, 1516064400, 
1593478800), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
    NR = c("CH-1000", " CH-1279", "CH-1392", 
    "CH-0534", "CH-0835", " CH-0910", "CH-0748", 
    "CH-0589", "CH-0675", "CH-0500", "CH-1243", 
    "CH-0635", "CH-1181", "CH-0791", "CH-0755", 
    "CH-1069", "CH-0640", "CH-1229", "CH-1856", 
    "CH-0116", "CH-0767", "CH-1126", "CH-0863", 
    "CH-1141", "CH-1858", "CH-0899", "CH-0005", 
    "CH-0225", "CH-0175", "CH-1764", "CH-1017", 
    "CH-0497", "CH-0771", "CH-0041", "CH-0816", 
    "CH-1046", "CH-0439", "CH-0930", "CH-1350", 
    "CH-0641", "CH-1057", "CH-1021", "CH-0503", 
    "CH-0553", "CH-1738", "CH-1379", "CH-0774", 
    "CH-0442", "CH-1113", "CH-1503"), PAT = c("101-1000", 
    "101-1279", "101-1392", "101-534", "101-835", "101-910", 
    "101-748", "101-589", "101-675", "101-500", "101-1243", "101-635", 
    "101-1181", "101-791", "101-755", "101-1069", "101-640", 
    "101-1229", "101-1856", "101-116", "101-767", "101-1126", 
    "101-863", "101-1141", "101-1858", "101-899", "101-5", "101-225", 
    "101-175", "101-1764", "101-1017", "101-497", "101-771", 
    "101-41", "101-816", "101-1046", "101-439", "101-930", "101-1350", 
    "101-641", "101-1057", "101-1021", "101-503", "101-553", 
    "101-1738", "101-1379", "101-774", "101-442", "101-1113", 
    "101-1503"), INT1 = c(NA, NA, NA, 280035, 280040, NA, 
    280040, 280040, 285030, 245040, NA, 280035, NA, NA, 280040, 
    NA, 220035, NA, NA, 280040, 280040, NA, 245005, NA, NA, 275005, 
    240070, 220035, 280040, NA, NA, 280040, 280040, 240005, 280040, 
    NA, 280040, 240005, 245040, 240030, NA, NA, 260010, NA, NA, 
    NA, 280040, NA, NA, NA), INT2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 280040, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 240030, NA, 260005, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA), INT3 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), INT4 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), INTX1 = c(NA, 280005, 220035, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 280050, NA, 240080, 280050, NA, 240085, NA, 
    280050, 270010, NA, NA, 280050, NA, 280005, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 275045, 280050, NA, NA, NA, NA, 245005, NA, NA, 245040, 
    NA, NA, 280050, NA, NA, 220035, 280050, NA, 255005, 280050, 
    220005), INTX2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 240085, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 280050, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), INTX3 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), INTX4 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), KAT = c(1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -50L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

What I needed to do first was
first, to recode some values from INT1:INT4 and INTX1:INTX4 and put them in new columns. To this aim, I used long_pivot as below:

```r
    longDATA <- DATA %>% 
                  pivot_longer(cols = c('INT1':'INTX4'),
                  names_to = "INT", values_to = "Code")
```

Then I used the long list to mutate new variables as below:

```r
    longDATA1 <- longDATA %>% mutate(palm = case_when(Code == 210025 ~ 1))


    longDATA2 <- longDATA1 %>% mutate(bio = case_when(Code == 210015 ~ '12.06.25',Code == 210020 ~ '12.07.25',Code == 275015 ~ '12.06.25',Code == 275020 ~ '12.07.25'))
                                                                 
    longDATA3 <- longDATA2 %>% mutate(EPX = case_when(Code == 280005 ~ 1, Code == 280010 ~ 1))
```

Then I need to return it to wide format. I used the code below:

```r
    WideDATA <- longDATA3 %>% pivot_wider(names_from = INT, values_from = Code)
```

Below you can see the output but it does not show the problem as I have a huge dataset. I realized the number of rows has changed from 2480 (my initial data before doing longer-pivot)to 2633 (the Wide data).I realized that the added rows are created when in one of the EPX, bio or palm columns a value has been recoded. for example if there is a row where INT1 and INT2 are filled with values other than NA (e.g., 280010 and 280040), EPX is assigned value 1, based on the mutation that we did earlier. However, EPX=1 and INT1=280010 appear in one row and 280040 appears in another row. like the photo below.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjEea.png

I have spent a week to figure this out but no luck. I would highly appreciate your advice.

```r
structure(list(ID = c("101", "101", "101", "101", "101", "101", 
"101", "101", "101", "101", "101", "101", "101", "101", "101", 
"101", "101", "101", "101", "101", "101", "101", "101", "101", 
"101", "101", "101", "101", "101", "101", "101", "101", "101", 
"101", "101", "101", "101", "101", "101", "101", "101", "101", 
"101", "101", "101", "101", "101", "101", "101", "101"), IDA = c("1000", 
"1279", "1392", "534", "835", "910", "748", "589", "675", "500", 
"1243", "635", "1181", "791", "755", "1069", "640", "1229", "1856", 
"116", "767", "1126", "863", "1141", "1858", "899", "5", "225", 
"175", "1764", "1017", "497", "771", "41", "816", "1046", "439", 
"930", "1350", "641", "1057", "1021", "503", "553", "1738", "1379", 
"774", "442", "1113", "1503"), DATE = structure(c(1497315600, 
1552352400, 1552957200, 1390438800, 1439427600, 1479776400, 1455757200, 
1402534800, 1409187600, 1383008400, 1536022800, 1414630800, 1545094800, 
1551142800, 1461805200, 1483405200, 1420506000, 1534813200, 1493600400, 
1348448400, 1458176400, 1521075600, 1464656400, 1527555600, 1504573200, 
1478134800, 1278378000, 1320886800, 1309395600, 1598576400, 1500512400, 
1385600400, 1436403600, 1284426000, 1430960400, 1485824400, 1381971600, 
1477962000, 1510023600, 1420509600, 1508806800, 1499302800, 1386205200, 
1379466000, 1555290000, 1565226000, 1435798800, 1494896400, 1516064400, 
1593478800), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
    NR = c("CH-1000", " CH-1279", "CH-1392", 
    "CH-0534", "CH-0835", " CH-0910", "CH-0748", 
    "CH-0589", "CH-0675", "CH-0500", "CH-1243", 
    "CH-0635", "CH-1181", "CH-0791", "CH-0755", 
    "CH-1069", "CH-0640", "CH-1229", "CH-1856", 
    "CH-0116", "CH-0767", "CH-1126", "CH-0863", 
    "CH-1141", "CH-1858", "CH-0899", "CH-0005", 
    "CH-0225", "CH-0175", "CH-1764", "CH-1017", 
    "CH-0497", "CH-0771", "CH-0041", "CH-0816", 
    "CH-1046", "CH-0439", "CH-0930", "CH-1350", 
    "CH-0641", "CH-1057", "CH-1021", "CH-0503", 
    "CH-0553", "CH-1738", "CH-1379", "CH-0774", 
    "CH-0442", "CH-1113", "CH-1503"), PAT = c("101-1000", 
    "101-1279", "101-1392", "101-534", "101-835", "101-910", 
    "101-748", "101-589", "101-675", "101-500", "101-1243", "101-635", 
    "101-1181", "101-791", "101-755", "101-1069", "101-640", 
    "101-1229", "101-1856", "101-116", "101-767", "101-1126", 
    "101-863", "101-1141", "101-1858", "101-899", "101-5", "101-225", 
    "101-175", "101-1764", "101-1017", "101-497", "101-771", 
    "101-41", "101-816", "101-1046", "101-439", "101-930", "101-1350", 
    "101-641", "101-1057", "101-1021", "101-503", "101-553", 
    "101-1738", "101-1379", "101-774", "101-442", "101-1113", 
    "101-1503"), palm = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), bio= c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), EPx = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA),  INT1 = c(NA, NA, NA, 280035, 280040, NA, 
    280040, 280040, 285030, 245040, NA, 280035, NA, NA, 280040, 
    NA, 220035, NA, NA, 280040, 280040, NA, 245005, NA, NA, 275005, 
    240070, 220035, 280040, NA, NA, 280040, 280040, 240005, 280040, 
    NA, 280040, 240005, 245040, 240030, NA, NA, 260010, NA, NA, 
    NA, 280040, NA, NA, NA), INT2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 280040, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 240030, NA, 260005, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA), INT3 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), INT4 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), INTX1 = c(NA, 280005, 220035, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 280050, NA, 240080, 280050, NA, 240085, NA, 
    280050, 270010, NA, NA, 280050, NA, 280005, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 275045, 280050, NA, NA, NA, NA, 245005, NA, NA, 245040, 
    NA, NA, 280050, NA, NA, 220035, 280050, NA, 255005, 280050, 
    220005), INTX2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 240085, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 280050, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), INTX3 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), INTX4 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), KAT = c(1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -50L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: This code gives me the expected result (no new rows) when I run it. Can you please share a sample of your actual dataset using dput()?

Comment: you are missing parenthesis at the end `)` it might be adding with your next code. fixing it and let us know. here the fix: `data2<- data1 %>% mutate(NewCode= case_when(Code == 12~ 1, Code == 15~ 1))`

Comment: @Seth as you recommended I added the sample data.

Comment: @RuamPimentel Sorry it was missed by mistake. Would you loo at the updated question please?

Comment: I think you are missing the specification to what `case_when()` should do when the conditions are not met. Try including `TRUE ~ NA` at the end of each `case_when()`

Comment: @RuamPimentel Thanks for your comment. But still the same problem. I suspect that the problem is with pivoting. Is it possible that because of so many NA values pivoting is changing something in data?

Comment: See my answer below. It fixed the data you showed.

Comment: @RuamPimentel The Number of rows will be equal but I noticed It has omitted the three columns I added (i.e., palm, bio, EPX).

Answer (score 0):

I copied pasted your code and both the DATA and WideDATA objects have the same number of rows (10), just with the desired variables added in WideDATA. Its possible there is something in your full data set that is creating the additional rows. I see some NAs in the sample you shared, and its worth noting that case_when doesn't treat those specially. If you need them handled as NA explicitly, you need to include `is.na` in a conditional statement. If sharing the full data set isn't possible, maybe randomly sampling would help.

*e.g.* `dput(sample_n(DATA, 50))`

I'm adding this as an answer though I realize it may need further editing as I couldn't usefully share the following in a comment.

In the code below I mostly kept your examples intact, but put everything into a single piped chunk of code. It might be simpler to stick with `if_else` in cases where there's only a single condition, but there's no harm using `case_when` throughout if you prefer the syntax.

You'll note I include `TRUE ~ ...` in each. Without a way to evaluate general cases, you get NA whenever the explicit statements aren't true.

Hopefully this lets you spot what is happening in your full data set, and if not please continue to update the question.

```r
library(tidyverse)

DATA <- structure(list(ID = c("101", "101", "101", "101", "101", "101","101", "101", "101", "101"), IDA = c("1", "1", "2", "3", "4","5", "5", "1859", "1860", "1861"), DATE = structure(c(1300928400,1277946000, 1277946000, 1278550800, 1278550800, 1453770000, 1329958800,1506474000, 1485133200, 1485133200), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct","POSIXt")), NR = c("CH-0001", "CH-0001","CH-0002", "CH-0003", "CH-0004", "CH-0005","CH-0005", "CH-1859", "CH-1860", "CH-1861"), PAT = c("101-1", "101-1", "101-2", "101-3", "101-4", "101-5","101-5", "101-1859", "101-1860", "101-1861"), INT1 = c(245005,280040, 280040, 280040, 280040, 240040, 240040, NA, NA, NA),INT2 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), INT3 = c(NA_real_,NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), INT4 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_,NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,NA_real_, NA_real_), INTX1 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,NA_real_), INTX2 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), INTX173 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), INTX4 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), KAT = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA,-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

longDATA <- DATA %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c('INT1':'INTX4'),
               names_to = "INT", values_to = "Code") %>%
  mutate(
    palm = case_when(
      Code == 210025 ~ 1,
      TRUE ~ 0),
    bio = case_when(
      Code == 210015 ~ '12.06.25',
      Code == 210020 ~ '12.07.25',
      Code == 275015 ~ '12.06.25',
      Code == 275020 ~ '12.07.25',
      TRUE ~ ''
    ),
    EPX = case_when(
      Code == 280005 ~ 1,
      Code == 280010 ~ 1,
      TRUE ~ 0
    )
    ) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = INT,
              values_from = Code)

longDATA
#> # A tibble: 10 × 17
#>    ID    IDA   DATE                NR      PAT      KAT  palm bio     EPX   INT1
#>    <chr> <chr> <dttm>              <chr>   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1 101   1     2011-03-24 01:00:00 CH-0001 101-1      0     0 ""        0 245005
#>  2 101   1     2010-07-01 01:00:00 CH-0001 101-1      0     0 ""        0 280040
#>  3 101   2     2010-07-01 01:00:00 CH-0002 101-2      0     0 ""        0 280040
#>  4 101   3     2010-07-08 01:00:00 CH-0003 101-3      0     0 ""        0 280040
#>  5 101   4     2010-07-08 01:00:00 CH-0004 101-4      0     0 ""        0 280040
#>  6 101   5     2016-01-26 01:00:00 CH-0005 101-5      0     0 ""        0 240040
#>  7 101   5     2012-02-23 01:00:00 CH-0005 101-5      0     0 ""        0 240040
#>  8 101   1859  2017-09-27 01:00:00 CH-1859 101-1…     1     0 ""        0     NA
#>  9 101   1860  2017-01-23 01:00:00 CH-1860 101-1…     1     0 ""        0     NA
#> 10 101   1861  2017-01-23 01:00:00 CH-1861 101-1…     1     0 ""        0     NA
#> # … with 7 more variables: INT2 <dbl>, INT3 <dbl>, INT4 <dbl>, INTX1 <dbl>,
#> #   INTX2 <dbl>, INTX173 <dbl>, INTX4 <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you. I just updated the data and there seems to be different kinds of NAs. Could you take another look at it please? I am just going to see whether your solution works.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get the same result after adding TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, check where I noted `#fix`

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

longDATA <- DATA %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c('INT1':'INTX4'),
               names_to = "INT", values_to = "Code")

longDATA1 <- longDATA %>% mutate(palm = case_when(Code == 210025 ~ 1,
                                                  TRUE ~ NA_real_)) #fix

longDATA2 <- longDATA1 %>% mutate(bio = case_when(Code == 210015 ~ '12.06.25',
                                                  Code == 210020 ~ '12.07.25',
                                                  Code == 275015 ~ '12.06.25',
                                                  Code == 275020 ~ '12.07.25',
                                                  TRUE ~ NA_character_))#fix

longDATA3 <- longDATA2 %>% mutate(EPX = case_when(Code == 280005 ~ 1, 
                                                  Code == 280010 ~ 1,
                                                  TRUE ~ NA_real_))#fix

WideDATA <- longDATA3 %>% pivot_wider(id_cols = ID:KAT, #fix
                                      names_from = INT, values_from = Code)

#########
# Check #
#########
nrow(DATA)
#> [1] 50
nrow(WideDATA)
#> [1] 50
```